# Get values from a table with witn an interval of 20, 10, 5

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Hi I don't know if this was asked before but I would like to get the values from a table of id's and numbers (the numbers are ranged from 1 - 190) with a given interval of 20, 10 and 5.

If I set the interval to 10 then I would get number values like 10, 20, 30, 40... 190 and if I set it to 20 then I would get values like 20, 40, 60 and so on.

I've tried to use **for loops** but performance and speed wise is not very efficient.

I'm using PHP to query data in Postgres.

Here's my sample codes:

```
$interval = intval($_REQUEST['interval']);

    $sql_last = 'SELECT MAX(elevation) AS elev FROM "Contour"';
    $result_last = pg_prepare($conn, 'query_last', $sql_last);
    $result_last = pg_execute($conn, 'query_last', array());

    $row_last = pg_fetch_array($result_last, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC);
    $max_elev = $row_last['elev'];

    for($x = $interval; $x < $max_elev; $x + $interval) {
        $sql = 'SELECT id, elevation FROM "Contour" WHERE elevation = $1';
        $result = pg_prepare($conn, $x, $sql);
        $result = pg_execute($conn, $x, array($x));

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate a series with these values, you can do:

```
select generate_series(0, 190, 10) as val
```

If you want to include this in a query like yours:

```
select c.*
from contour c join
     (select generate_series(min(c2.elev), max(c2.elev), 10) as elev
      from contour c2
     ) cc
     on c.elevation = c2.elev;
```

You might want to replace `min(c2.elev)` with `0`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon :) I've your generate_series() function and it works! But adding it to my query I get an error like column "c.elev" does not exist. Might be my version of Postgres (I use Postgres v1.16.1). I'll try to see if there's a Postgres equivalent of it.

Comment: @Loupi . . . I think that should be `elevation`.

Answer (score 1):

With a for loop you're doing a lot of db calls. I would do two calls. First query would get the max ID in the table. Create an int array or list with the id's in the selected increments going up to the max id. Output the list to a comma separated string. Then the second query with "where ID in (id string)".

The second query will be larger but most of your time is in the process of making the query repeatedly no so much the size of the data coming back.